# How to target <tr> which contain <th>? (not which contain <td>)?

Tags: html, css

How would I select all `<tr>` which contain a `<th>` but not `<td>` with CSS. Is this possible?

The context is that I have implemented a zebra striped background with CSS that I do not want applied to the header rows. This also got me wondering whether this kind of selection in general is possible with CSS (without adding custom classes).

A solution with vanilla HTML and CSS would be ideal.

Table Code Below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>This is header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Data 1</td>
    <td> $125.00 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Data 2 </td>
    <td> $175.00 </td>
  </tr>
    <th>This is another header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Data 3</td>
    <td> $100.00 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Data 4 </td>
    <td> $200.00 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS for the zebra stripes below:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use thead and tbody elements? If not, you can include th's in thead.

Comment: I did not consider that. Thank you!

Comment: If I may ask, why does using the <thead> and <tbody> work for this? I.e. How does CSS know to ignore the <thead> when the CSS selector is "tr:nth-child(even){}" ?

Answer (score 3):

I would say: just add a class name to your <tr> for the ones that only contain <th>

For example:

#### HTML

```html
<table>
  <tr class = "headrow">
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "row">
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```css
.headrow
{
   /* styling for row with <th> */
}
.row
{
   /* styling for row with <td> */
}
```

## OR

If you know that the <tr> with the <th> will always be the first in a table you can do it like this:

#### HTML

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```css
table tr
{
   /* styling for all <tr> */
}
.table tr:first-of-type
{
   /* styling for row with <th> */
}
```

Comment: This does select what I am trying to select. However, I was wondering specifically if there is a way to do this purely using CSS selectors ex post facto.

Comment: @PabloGrillo Ive edited my answer, if it suits your needs please mark my answer please accept my answer.